# About deprecation and unit testing in Pharo

Tags: pharo

sometimes, it is better to temporarily use a deprecated method than to create several branches of a project to support several versions of Pharo. At least, that's what I sometimes do. However, calling a deprecated method makes my unit-tests fail in Pharo 3.0.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shouldn't it be sufficient to switch off deprecation warnings? I think the reason is that opening the deprecation warning is based on an exception that the test case catches.